# How to implement group_concat with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, group-concat

I have two tables :

**menuChapters**

| id | chapterName | chapterOrder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | integer | 1 |
| 2 | double | 2 |

and  **menuUnits** :

| id | chapter_id | unitName | unitsOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | uN1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | uN2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | uN5 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | un7 | 2 |

what i want is to get a table like below in the end :

| chapterName | unit_names |
| --- | --- |
| integer | uN1, uN2 |
| double | un5, uN7 |

I have tried:

```
SELECT menuChapters.chapterName, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(menuUnits.unitName ORDER BY menuUnits.unitsOrder SEPARATOR ', ')
          FROM menuChapters
          LEFT JOIN menuUnits ON menuUnits.chapter_id = menuChapters.id
          WHERE menuChapters.class = '13' AND menuChapters.course = '31'
          GROUP BY menuChapters.chapterName
          ORDER BY menuChapters.chapterOrder
```

but i get *unit_names* in the wrong order:

| chapterName | unit_names |
| --- | --- |
| integer | uN2, uN1 |
| double | un7, uN5 |

What i want is the following:

| chapterName | unit_names |
| --- | --- |
| integer | uN1, uN2 |
| double | un5, uN7 |

- ORDER BY seems not to work in GROUP_CONCAT the way i use it*

Comment: which version of mysql you use?

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.12-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT() with ORDER BY is working here. Please check this version wise query.

```
-- MySQL (v5.6)
SELECT mc.chapterName
     , GROUP_CONCAT(mu.unitName ORDER BY mu.unitsOrder SEPARATOR ', ') unit_names
FROM menuChapters mc
LEFT JOIN menuUnits mu
       ON mc.id = mu.chapter_id
GROUP BY mc.chapterName
ORDER BY mc.chapterOrder;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=87a41d6b0d2316803636e6fdeae08a53

```
-- MySQL (v5.7 & v5.8)
SELECT mc.chapterName
     , GROUP_CONCAT(mu.unitName ORDER BY mu.unitsOrder SEPARATOR ', ') unit_names
FROM menuChapters mc
LEFT JOIN menuUnits mu
       ON mc.id = mu.chapter_id
GROUP BY mc.chapterName, mc.chapterOrder
ORDER BY mc.chapterOrder;
```

**Please check from url below**

For version 5.8 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=628c4fde8d17d61f1f3db7f3478a39ea

For version 5.7 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3405f8dea89b8033ad96037cb42ba5da

Comment: what  if i wanted to implement this only for chapterName with id = 1 (as seen in menuChapters table) . That s why i also have the WHERE clause

Comment: @alex I removed where clause for execute the query. Because at your given table structure class column was missing. My aim was to show order by works at group_concat(). You can add where clause as your need. If my answer help you then please mark it as accepted along with upvote so that others can pick it without any doubt.